# Dentro de Visual Studio 2015, cómo revertir un commit en Git?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, git

Tengo un commit hecho por un desarrollador en el repositorio remoto Git alojado en VSTS que necesita ser revertido. Desde Visual Studio, sin command prompt cómo revertir el commit?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Nota: En la imagen aparece un repositorio de GitHub, pero los pasos indicados son válidos tanto para GitHub, VSTS o cualquier repo de Git

En el Team Explorer anda a *Branches*

[image: Team Explorer -> Home -> Branches]

Clic derecho en un branch que contenga al commit que desees revertir y selecciona *View History*

[image: View History]

Clic derecho en el commit deseado y clic en *Revert*

[image: Revert]